# How to get EndRecurrenceDate using microsoft graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, mapi, microsoft-graph-calendar, extended-properties

I am trying to get ***EndRecurrenceDate*** using ms graph api by referring this documents .[link 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxprops/816378cf-07ef-4926-b7d2-53475792403d)

none of followings didn't work for me . what could be the reasons

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/{event-id}==?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String {6ED8DA90-450B-101B-98DA-00AA003F1305} Id 0x0000000F')
```

.
I chnaged expand query but it also does not give any value for singleValueExtendedProperties in API response

```
$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'Date {6ED8DA90-450B-101B-98DA-00AA003F1305} Id 0x0000000F')    

$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String {6ED8DA90-450B-101B-98DA-00AA003F1305} Id 0x0000000F')  

$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String {6ED8DA90-450B-101B-98DA-00AA003F1305} Name PidLidEndRecurrenceTime')
```

Answer (score 0):

In MS-Graph API, please retrieve the seriesMaster by passing the seriesMasterId corresponding to the given event:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0

For verification, please check the field "type" which specifies the event type. It should have value "seriesMaster".

In the seriesMaster that has been retrieved, the field "end" will represent the end date of the recurrence.